# R package DiagrammeR output graph options

Tags: r, diagrammer

A quick question regarding using DiagrammeR package. I'm trying to create a diagram and output it as an image in png format or use it to generate diagram directly in Rmarkdown. However, the output always has original DiagrammeR codes.
I tried set echo=F in Rmarkdown, but still have no luck. Are there other more straightforward methods to get the diagram out?

My r markdown codes:

```
covid <- "graph LR;A(GPS data)-->C{Analytic data};
B[Weather data]-->C{Analytic data};
D[Masking mandatory/compliance]-->C{Analytic data};
E[Demographics]-->C{Analytic data};
F[Covid-testing result]-->C{Analytic data};
G[Covid confirmed cases]-->C{Analytic data};
C{Analytic data}-->M[Modeling];
M[Modeling]-->V[Data visualization]

style A fill:#E5E25F;  style B fill:#87AB51; style C fill:#3C8937;
style D fill:#23772C;  style E fill:#B6E6E6;
style F fill:#E5E25F;  style G fill:#87AB51; style M fill:#3C8937;
style V fill:#23772C;  "

DiagrammeR::mermaid(covid)
```

Any suggest on how to achieve this goal?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is important for `DiagrammeR`, you should not use the ";" signs in your code. You can use the following code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "2022-07-22"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(DiagrammeR)
covid <- "graph LR;
A(GPS data)-->C{Analytic data}
B[Weather data]-->C{Analytic data}
D[Masking mandatory/compliance]-->C{Analytic data}
E[Demographics]-->C{Analytic data}
F[Covid-testing result]-->C{Analytic data}
G[Covid confirmed cases]-->C{Analytic data}
C{Analytic data}-->M[Modeling]
M[Modeling]-->V[Data visualization]

style A fill:#E5E25F  style B fill:#87AB51 style C fill:#3C8937;
style D fill:#23772C  style E fill:#B6E6E6
style F fill:#E5E25F  style G fill:#87AB51 style M fill:#3C8937;
style V fill:#23772C  "

mermaid(covid)
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Quinten! You solved this problem nicely!